# How to make a non-XML PopupWindow appear on the screen in Android

Tags: android, visible, popupwindow

I've created a class that generates a PopupWindow based on parameters fed into it. I believe this will suit my needs better than manipulating XML-based content for my PopupWindow.

Creating the window and it's content seems to go through smoothly - it's actually getting that content to appear on the screen that I haven't been able to manage yet. The problem is that I haven't been able to find an example of PopupWindow code in use that doesn't rely on the LayoutInflater function to place it on the screen. As my PopupWindow isn't generated from an XML file, I can't use LayoutInflater to place it on the screen.

Something else I should probably explain is that my PopupWindow-generating class is **in it's own file**. i.e. It is not a subclass of an Activity file. I've done it this way so that I can easilly copy my custom-PopupWindow class to any future projects I might develop.

Here is the basic layout of my class:

```
class myPopup extends Object {

    public myPopup(parameters){
        ViewGroup winBody;
        // "winbBody" will be the content of the PopupWindow.
        // Code that fills and adjusts "winBody" based on the parameters goes here.

        int width = //Determined by parameters.
        int height = //Determined by parematers.
        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(winBody, width, height, true);
        //This is as far as I seem to get before getting stuck.
    }

}
```

I gather that I am supposed to somehow use the PopupWindow function "showAtLocation", but I am unclear what parameters I am supposed to use for this. Could someone please tell me how to get my popup window to appear on the screen? Hopefully in the very center of it. :)

Comment: I am exactly sure about the problem, but you can create PopupWindow layout programmatically, in java, which could mean that your window could be kind of dynamic from call to call

Comment: Yes, that's more or less what the code above does. (I haven't provided the full code in this question as it is quite long and most of it doesn't relate to my problem.)

Comment: what about using update method of popupWindow?

Comment: "update" seems to require a "View" parameter as an "anchor" (I assume this means a parent "View" object, which the PopupWindow will become a child of.) What value should I place there?

Comment: not sure :) , can investigate, try my post first, maybe it will work

Comment: No, it doesn't. The app runs, but it is completely blank. For one thing, you reference a variable "but" that doesn't seem to have been defined anywhere.  For another thing, in "setContentView", you seem to be making "layout" the content of the popupwindow. But in the next line, you seem to be trying to set the location of the popupwindow INSIDE "layout". This seems illogical. How can any object be placed inside it's own child? Wouldn't that cause a paradox?

Comment: now i have updated the post and that one is working, sorry, before couldn't test the result :)

Comment: Okay, that one actually *does* work. Although I can't understand why. isn't the line "popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)" placing the popUp inside "layout"? And isn't layout the content of the popUp window? Therfore, isn't that command placing the popup window inside itelf? (an impossible action) At what point does the code instruct "popUp" that it's supposed to appear on the screen?

Comment: i actually made a mistake, wrote wrong layout, but that was weird that it actually worked, you are right. The right one supposed to be mainLayout instead of layout in popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); I think what android is trying to do is to redraw a field, where popup is about to be shown, so you tell to clean area layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0 and then you update this area, but already with the textview of that popupwindow. But this is just an assumption

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

you may define the whole popup window as an activity and just make its background disapear, so it will look like a popup window:

```
<style name="MyTransparentPopup">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

---

```
public class PopupWindowActivity extends Activity {

    PopupWindow popUp;
    LinearLayout layout;
    TextView tv;
    LayoutParams params;
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    Button but;
    boolean click = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
        layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        tv = new TextView(this);
        but = new Button(this);
        but.setText("Show popup");
        but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (click) {
                    popUp.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    popUp.update(0, 0, 300, 80);
                    click = false;
                } else {
                    popUp.dismiss();
                    click = true;
                }
            }

        });
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        tv.setText("Hello popup");
        layout.addView(tv, params);
        popUp.setContentView(layout);

        mainLayout.addView(but, params);
        setContentView(mainLayout);
    }
    }
```